# Display product dimension in WooCommerce product summary

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, dimensions

In WooCommerce I would like to Display *Product Dimensions* from product metabox in summary of single product pages. Is it possible?

Any track is appreciated.

---

**Edit** - *More detail*:

I have an option in my theme setting like this:
[image: Theme Setting Option]

When I enable this option I have product page like this image:
[image: Single Product Page]

I'd like to disable this option from my theme setting and then use a snippet to show *Dimensions* only.

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec ; I've edited my question with more detail;  I'd like to show *Dimensions* of product in one row and two columns.

Comment: May be it would more useful if you also mention the name of the theme that you are using.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Yes; I don't see , "_Additional Information_" tab when this setting is *ON*; I'd like to show this tab and also I want to show _Dimentsions_ under _Short Description_ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following hooked function will display formatted product dimensions *(only)* under product short description in product single pages:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_product_formated_dimensions_table', 25 );
function display_product_formated_dimensions_table(){
    global $product;

    if ( $product->has_dimensions() ) {
        echo '<table class="shop_attributes"><tr>
            <th>' . __( 'Dimensions', 'woocommerce' ) . '</th>
            <td class="product_dimensions">' . esc_html( wc_format_dimensions( $product->get_dimensions( false ) ) ) . '</td>
        </tr></table>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: To everyone: please be aware that WooCommerce's code snippet did not work, but this one did.  Just add the "Code Snippet" extension then add this snippet and it shows up!